# Facebook like button starts counting on 424, not at zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am adding the Facebook Like Button counter to my website.
As detailed in FB page, I am adding the code for the like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="www.my-site.com" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Then I refresh the site and the button appears with the "0" likes count next to it. Then I click on it, and the count changes to "1".

On the other hand, I am executing the GET query to check the that the like has been registered by FB, so I execute this URL on my browser:

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.my-url.com&format=json

And I get as result the following stats:

```
...
"share_count":135,"like_count":269,"comment_count":21,"total_count":425
```

The error is that I have just added the first like, so there is no explanation to have 269/425 like counts.

If I refresh the site where I have added the like button, now I see that the count of likes is 425 ( just like JSON GET query says). If I remove the like it goes to 424, and if I click "like" again, it goes up to 425 once again.

So my question is, why does it starts with  269 / 425 likes? Is there any offset on facebook stats to make the websites seems with more likes than what they really have?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, check your URL in the debug tool to verify that all OG meta data is in order. Perhaps the URL has been liked by other people before? (Just because you have set up a like button for it for the first time, does not necessarily mean no one else has done so before.) Real URL to have a look at the issue might also help.

Comment: Should I add OG meta in that URL? 
Now it does not have any meta value. I thought OG meta was for sharing URL using the FB API.

The URL was not public yet, and one second before I liked, was zero, and just when I clicked, it went to 425. Only me knows of that URL so there is no way to have other likes.

The real URL I was using is http://www.tripin.travel/ranking/villa-traful/a-2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, why does it starts with 269 / 425 likes?

Because, [as the debug tool shows](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tripin.travel%2Franking%2Fvilla-traful%2Fa-2016), you have the canonical URL under `http://www.tripin.travel/ranking/villa-traful/a-2016` set to `http://www.tripin.travel/ranking/villa-traful/` – so Facebook takes the latter as the “real” URL, and accumulates the likes on that one.

That also explains, why you saw 0 likes on your first try - Facebook did not know that new URL yet, so it did also not know that the canonical points somewhere else. Only after you first liked it, the FB scraper has fetched the information from the URL.

So: Set your canonical URLs *properly*.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the second URL, it doesn’t seem to be a `<link rel=canonical>`, but you have explicitly set `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tripin.travel/ranking/villa-traful/"/>` (didn’t you say you did not have any OG meta data in that document?) You need to fix this, so that it points to the actual URL you want to like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It all make sense now.
I will try that fixes, but it seems to be the correct way to do it.